# ArcGIS Pro can't count overlapping polygons because of self-intersection

Tags: shapefile, polygon, arcgis-pro, geometry, intersect

I'm trying to use the Count Overlapping Features tool in arcgis pro, but it keeps failing due to 'invalid topology'. Some research points out this has to do with invalid geometries, so I do check geometry and it says there are self-intersecting polygons. When I try to run 'Repair self-intersection' it goes through all polygons, and then for each it will result in a warning 'Feature x overlaps itself'. I know that already, I'm trying to fix it, but it doesn't seem to be working.
Repair geometry also doesn't work.

I don't really understand what's going on here:
Either all individual features (individual polygons) self-intersect, which is strange as there's 2000 of them and it doesn't look like they're self intersecting.
OR it considers them all one shape as they're part of a shapefile, and it's saying it's a problem the individual features (polygons) are overlapping. But that needs to be the case for a tool like 'count overlapping features' to be meaningful?

Comment: I suggest you use the Repair Geometry tool, not "Repair self-intersection". Shapefile is really the wrong format to do this -- file geodatabase is much more robust.

Comment: If I download something as a shapefile, how do i converse it into a gdb?

Comment: Create a file geodatabase, and drag and drop it in?

Comment: Well yes, I just don't understand how that would fix any geometric issues inherent in the shapefile.
Anyways, back on-topic. I run repair geometry which takes a while. I run a check geometry and there's no issues reported. Then I run 'Count overlapping features again' and I still get  ERROR 160196: Invalid Topology

Comment: Moving your data out of the archaic shapefile format into a geodatabase is the way forward as geodatabase featureclass have XY tolerance/resolution (read the help file). But you say you imported and it still errors? I think you need to share your data via dropbox/drive so someone can have a look at it. As I'm surprised the repair geometry has not worked.

Comment: In another attempt to circumvent this issue; is there an easy way to identify the polygons that have an invalid geometry and delete them? E.g. when I run the 'count overlapping features' on the first 100 polygons it works, if I select the first 500 it doesn't.

Comment: You did a Select or created a file from the first 100 records? Tools such as Geometry Check and Upgrade do not honor selects. They work with the table on disk. File geodbs data is more likely to work with geoprocessing tools than a shape file.

Comment: I did a select, which worked for the first 100 polygons of the shapefile.